# SQL Server XQuery check data values before insert

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2012

This is all on SQL Server 2012.

I have TSQL to create a XQuery statement to shred and insert some XML

The code looks something like this:

```
declare @xmlasXML xml
set @xmlasXML = '
      <data Store="R262">
        <s Item1="10" Item2="-1" />
        <s Item1="33.2" Item2="55"  />
      </data>
'

insert TableX(OldPrice, Price) 
   select 
      c.value('@Item1[1]','decimal(15,2)') as OldPrice, 
      c.value('@ut[1]','int') as Price
   FROM 
      @xmlasXML.nodes('/data/s') T(c)
```

I want to add some data validation into the insert statement above (I don't want to land the data and then have to churn through it again to validate every data point)...

When I say data validation here's what I'm saying:

- If the value for Item1 is between 1 and 15 then use it for the insert otherwise insert NULL
- IF the value for Item2 is between -10 and 1000 then use it for the insert otherwise insert NULL.

I have see some information on XQuery I think that XQuery has conditional logic that can handle but none of the example I have found align with the way I'm building and doing my `INSERT` / `SELECT` statement.

If there is a better way, I'm all for it - as long as I don't have to shred the data twice.

Thanks in advance for your time!  Hope someone out there can help me knock this out!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @xmlasXML xml
    set @xmlasXML = '
          <data Store="R262">
            <s Item1="10" Item2="-1" />
            <s Item1="33.2" Item2="55"  />
          </data>';

;with TMP as (
    select c.value('@Item1[1]','decimal(15,2)') as OldPrice,
           c.value('@ut[1]','int') as Price
      FROM @xmlasXML.nodes('/data/s') T(c)
)
    insert TableX (OldPrice, Price) 
    select case when OldPrice between 1 and 15 then OldPrice end,
           case when Price between -1 and 1000 then Price end
      from TMP;
```